# Google Drive SDK JavaScript 404 Error

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

We are getting since yesterday an error each time we try to execute any Drive Method from Javascript Library, such as:

- gapi.client.drive.files.get({'fileId': RootFolderID});
- gapi.client.drive.children.list({'folderId' : FolderGUID, 'q': 'trashed = ' + trashed});

Or any other.

When we execute this code code:

```
    var RootFolderID = "0Bz9GhmOJPXaDMmlnc1UtNmFKb28";
    var GetFileInfo = gapi.client.drive.files.get({'fileId': RootFolderID});
    GetFileInfo.execute(function(GetFileInfoResp){
        log("RootFolderID", RootFolderID);
        log("GetFileInfoResp", GetFileInfoResp);
    });
```

We get the following error

RootFolderID - 0Bz9GhmOJPXaDMmlnc1UtNmFKb28

GetFileInfoResp- Object {code: 404, message: "Not Found", data: Array[1], error: Object}
code: 404

data: Array[1]

error: Object

message: "Not Found"

**proto**: Object

**Two days ago the same code was working fine.**

Anyone has the same problem? do you have any clue?

When we try to execute the same method from the Drive SDK help, it works.

Comment: I have alredy opened an issue in the google-api-javascript-client site

Comment: Same issue here. Works fine with raw http requests, so it seems to be related to the javascript client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sergey Pisarenko spisarenko@google.com
12:41 wrote...

to google-appengi., google-cloud-s., gce-operations

Google API JavaScript client functionality has already been restored for some users, and we expect a resolution for all users in the near future. Please note this time frame is an estimate and may change. Further information for customers with a support contract will also be available in the Google Enterprise Support Center. We will provide an update by 12:30 GMT.

Answer (score 2):

We have the same problem. Please vote for the issues 136 & 137 https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/issues/list

Answer (score 0):

the issue has been solved by Google.

It seems they did a wrong udpate of libraries.

They have rollback the libraries and now it's working fine again.

Thanks and regards,

Fernando.